# Matplotlib (GridSpec) - Subplot axis labels being cut-off? Tried `tight_layout`

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels, subplot

I'm using GridSpec to organise subplots. I have a shared `colorbar` for all the plots.

All suggestions online seem to point out that `tight_layout()` is the way to fix issues with axis labels cutting off, however this doesn't seem to be working here (unless it comes in another form which I am unaware of).

I have also tried using the `rect` parameter of `tight_layout` for `fig`, `plt`, and `gs`.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.colors
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,7,hspace=0.05,wspace=0.5, width_ratios=[1,1,1,1,1,1,0.1])
figure(num=None, figsize=(18, 2), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

data = np.random.rand(3,6,224,5)

for i in range(6):
    ax = plt.subplot(gs[0, i], projection='3d')
    p = ax.scatter(data[0,i,:,0], data[0,i,:,1], data[0,i,:,2], c=data[0,i,:,4], marker='o')
    title("Case " + str(i+1))
    ax.set_xlabel('Batch Size', linespacing=3)
    ax.set_ylabel('Window Size', linespacing=3)
    ax.set_zlabel('Neurons', linespacing=3)
    ax.xaxis.labelpad=20
    ax.yaxis.labelpad=20
    ax.zaxis.labelpad=10

cbar = plt.subplot(gs[0,6])
colorbar(p, cax=cbar, label='RMSE')

plt.show()
```

This generates the image below.

[image]

Comment: I think `tight_layout` will do the opposite of what you need here. Instead, make the figure margins *larger*, e.g. by using `bottom=0.3` or so.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Would you mind providing a specific example please? I've already tried `fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)`, `plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)`, and `ax.margins`. Are you referring to a different type of figure margin?

Comment: I was refering to `bottom=0.3` as in `fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)`. If you can provide a runnable example, I can modify it. See [mcve].

Comment: Apologise, I've edited the code so it runs now.

Answer (score 3):

As commented, setting the `bottom` parameter to a larger value, e.g. `bottom=0.3` would give you more space to accomodate the axes decorators.

In addition it may be useful to make the figure a little bit taller (e.g. 3 inch instead of 2) in order not to shrink the plots too much.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,7,hspace=0.05,wspace=0.5, bottom=0.3,
                       left=0.02, right=0.95, width_ratios=[1,1,1,1,1,1,0.1])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 3), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

data = np.random.rand(3,6,224,5)

for i in range(6):
    ax = plt.subplot(gs[0, i], projection='3d')
    p = ax.scatter(data[0,i,:,0], data[0,i,:,1], data[0,i,:,2], 
                   c=data[0,i,:,4], marker='o')
    ax.set_title("Case " + str(i+1))
    ax.set_xlabel('Batch Size', linespacing=3)
    ax.set_ylabel('Window Size', linespacing=3)
    ax.set_zlabel('Neurons', linespacing=3)
    ax.xaxis.labelpad=20
    ax.yaxis.labelpad=20
    ax.zaxis.labelpad=10

cbar = plt.subplot(gs[0,6])
fig.colorbar(p, cax=cbar, label='RMSE')

# This is only needed for jupyter
fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1]).axis("off")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Unfortunately in jupyter the `%matplotlib inline` backend always creates its images with a the `bbox_inches = "tight"` setting. So a workaround is to create some element in the figure that ensures that the "tight" area is large enough. Here, an option is to use `fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1]).axis("off")`.

Comment: Thank you! Although, when I try and run it, I get the same graph as before... I've just tried resetting some parameters to defaults: `mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)`. But, this doesn't seem to fix the issue either.

Comment: Oh, so when copying the code from this answer the output looks different than the image I show? I used python 2.7 with matplotlib 2.2.2 and the Qt4Agg backend, but that can't really matter. If you had set the rcParams `figure.autolayout` or `figure.constrained_layout.use` to True it could explain the difference, but it seems you can already exclude that (although I would have used `matplotlib.rcdefaults()` to return to the defaults). Which interpreter are you running this in? Can there be any other code being injected, still present?

Comment: I changed my backend type to `Qt4Agg`, but still had the same problem.  There is no residual code, I ran the code you posted in a fresh notebook with nothing in it. I found that saving the figure now doesn't have the issue (it did before). I'm not sure whether it's related to changing the backend or resetting my defaults that did it, but it works! Although it still doesn't output correctly in Jupyter.

Comment: Haha, it is pretty relevant that you are using Jupyter notebook. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help.